# PURE use default value

Tags: json, default-value

I'm using PURE from BeeBole for filling some HTML templates with JSON, everything works perfect except that I can't find how to pass a default value when a missing property, and I wanted to do this from this side since from the server there is nothing I can do. So for example I have this JSON object:

var example = {records: [ {id: '1', name: 'Bill', nick: 'B'}, {id: '2', name: 'Amy'} ]}

When I render this in a table, on the directive when I ask for 'nick' I get 'B' for the first and nothing for the second, but for this case I would like to set a default value such as '-' when the property is not found.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late on this one.
If you want to show the `nick` in a `SPAN`, it should look something like:

```
'span':function(){
  return this.nick || '-';
}
```

instead of:

```
'span':'nick'
```

You would probably get a quicker answer [on the forum](http://groups.google.com/group/Pure-Unobtrusive-Rendering-Engine)